# MySQL stored procedure return value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, return-value

I have to create an SP that returns a value if it's valid or not. But it doesn't return anything and I don't know, why?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `validar_egreso`(
    IN codigo_producto VARCHAR(100),
    IN cantidad INT,
    OUT valido INT(11)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE resta INT(11);
    SET resta = 0;

    SELECT (s.stock - cantidad) INTO resta
    FROM stock AS s
    WHERE codigo_producto = s.codigo;

    IF (resta > s.stock_minimo) THEN
        SET valido = 1;
    ELSE
        SET valido = -1;
    END IF;
    SELECT valido;
END
```

Comment: Use [exception handling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html) in your SP.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have done the stored procedure correctly  but I think you have not referenced the `valido` variable properly. I was looking at some examples and they have put an @ symbol before the  parameter like this `@Valido`

This statement `SELECT valido;` should be like this `SELECT @valido;`

Look at this link [mysql stored-procedure: out parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113579/mysql-stored-procedure-out-parameter). Notice the solution with 7 upvotes. He has reference the parameter with an @ sign, hence I suggested you add an @ sign before your parameter valido

I hope that works for you. if it does vote up and mark it as the answer. If not, tell me.

Comment: Putting @ infront of the variable makes it a session-specific user-defined variable, which works fine. You can also declare the variable as `DECLARE valido INT`.

Comment: The declaration, passing the OUT parameter, worked out for me.

Answer (score 13):

Add:

- `DELIMITER` at the beginning and end of the SP.
- DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `validar_egreso`;     at the beginning
- When calling the SP, use `@variableName`.

This works for me. (I modified some part of your script so ANYONE can run it with out having your tables).

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `validar_egreso`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE `validar_egreso` (
    IN codigo_producto VARCHAR(100),
    IN cantidad INT,
    OUT valido INT(11)
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE resta INT;
    SET resta = 0;

    SELECT (codigo_producto - cantidad) INTO resta;

    IF(resta > 1) THEN
       SET valido = 1;
    ELSE
       SET valido = -1;
    END IF;

    SELECT valido;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

-- execute the stored procedure
CALL validar_egreso(4, 1, @val);

-- display the result
select @val;
```

Answer (score 3):

Update your SP and handle exception in it using [declare handler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html) with [get diagnostics](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/get-diagnostics.html) so that you will know if there is an exception.
e.g.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `validar_egreso`(
IN codigo_producto VARCHAR(100),
IN cantidad INT,
OUT valido INT(11)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
    @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SELECT @p1, @p2;
END
DECLARE resta INT(11);
SET resta = 0;

SELECT (s.stock - cantidad) INTO resta
FROM stock AS s
WHERE codigo_producto = s.codigo;

IF (resta > s.stock_minimo) THEN
    SET valido = 1;
ELSE
    SET valido = -1;
END IF;
SELECT valido;
END
```

Comment: What is "GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1" here ?

Comment: The MySQL 5.6 parser tells me that the END statement on the SQLEXCEPTION handler block needs a semicolon, and that the DECLARE must precede the block that declares the handler. see "13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Syntax, " at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html.