# how to get output value in from procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(out myvalue int)
BEGIN
select count(*) from EventList_View group by eventId  into myvalue  ;
END
```

this is my Procedure i am calling this  Procedure call `test(@output);`
`select @output;` like this but i am unable to get value of output parameter as myvalue . while i am trying to execute `select count(*)` from EventList_View group by eventId  this query i am getting value 5 please tell me how to get output value where am doing wrong in procedure .

Comment: Do Tag which are related only to your Question. I think SQL Server Tag doesn't suits your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql stored-procedure: out parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113579/mysql-stored-procedure-out-parameter)

Comment: That is a horrible select stmt you have going there. Do you see why?

Comment: Well then let me tell ya. When you have more than one value of eventId in the table, you will get `Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row`

Comment: NO its contain only one count

Comment: It doesn't matter. You should not write code that could return more than one row of data into a variable set (in your case just 1 variable). And if your table only ever contains one distinct value for eventId in a table, why have it there anyway as a column. This is simple. Your code will blow up with an 1172 in the real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(out myvalue int)
BEGIN
select count(*) from (select * from events group by event_id) as totalcount into myvalue;


END
```

apply this query